# How to save a file in usb directory

Tags: linux, file, python-3.7, raspberry-pi4, shutil

I'm trying to move a file to a pen-drive using linux raspberry, python3, os and shutil, but i just receive errors.

When i try to save in a another directory (not usb), the code works great

```
import shutil
import os

original = '/home/guardian/shared/TestPath/New/'
new = '/media/guardian/GUARDIANT1/New/'

for dir, sub, arq in os.walk(original):
    for arch in arq:
        path = dir + arch
        new = new + arch
        
        shutil.move(src=path, dst=new)
```

i receive this error:

```
OSError: [Errno 18] Invalid cross-device link '/home/guardian/shared/TestPath/New/img1.jpg' ->  '/media/guardian/GUARDIANT1/New/img1'
```

Comment: Use `shutil.copy()` followed by `os.remove()`. It's a bug in `shutil.move()`, see the comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42392600/oserror-errno-18-invalid-cross-device-link)

Comment: Thus, duplicate of [OSError: \[Errno 18\] Invalid cross-device link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42392600/oserror-errno-18-invalid-cross-device-link)

Comment: @chickitychinachinesechicken it's not a copy of this question, please read my post again, that solution works only for normal directories, but for USB transfer it doesn't work

Comment: @JorgeAugustoWilchen - read the comments to the accepted answer. It **is** the same problem. Do as Barmar suggested.

Comment: I tried using that solution, but as I said before, it only worked in computer repositories, in pendrive repositories this error appears

Comment: In that case another alternative cause of the problem might be that what you're *trying* to copy aren't files but symlinks?

Comment: I made other changes, and the error is in the name of the files, it are saved in this format "yyyy/MM/DD - HH:MM:SEC.ms", this type of name that causes the file transfer error

Comment: after editing the name of the files, this method is effective